# Duplicate Anchor IDs and W3 Conventions

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, xhtml, w3c

I was converting a page with some outdated attributes to being more XHTML friendly today, and ran into the subject of the anchor tag. Specifically:
`<a name="someName"></a>`

After converting the anchor tags to `<a id="someName"></a>`, my IDE gave me some friendly advice about not using duplicate IDs in my anchor tags. Turns out, [so does W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3).

> The id and name attributes share the same name space. This means that they cannot both define an anchor with the same name in the same document. It is permissible to use both attributes to specify an element's unique identifier for the following elements: A, APPLET, FORM, FRAME, IFRAME, IMG, and MAP. When both attributes are used on a single element, their values must be identical.

The page works, rebelliously, *without any behavioral abnormality*, in spite of the duplicates.

The page logic guarantees that there will only be a single HTML element ever rendered with a given name or ID, so no duplicate href `#someName` ever exists.

With that in mind:

**Is the above usage case still breaking the W3C guideline for using duplicate names/IDs?**

It would take a good bit of effort to convert the page to using unique IDs, but there may be merit to doing so. I'm new at this, so apologies if I'm missing something purely philosophical or glaringly obvious.

Answer (score 3):

IDs are unique in the DOM.  This has an easily noticeable effect on JavaScript: `document.getElementById('someName')` will only select *one* of multiple `id="someName"` elements that may be available.  It's probably the first, but there is no way to guarantee which one.

Comment: This may be an obtuse follow-up question, but can it even select an Element of `id="someName"` which is currently set to `visible="false"`? If it never renders in markup, is it still "there" to JavaScript?

Comment: @TonyFiorentini yes it is definitely still "there" to JavaScript

Comment: After you said "DOM" (first time I've seen the word), I was able to find a related article. I now see how JavaScript is able to access a DOM Element in spite of its visibility. Thinking about it now, it's obvious that it would have to. That answers my question completely. Thanks!

Comment: Also, as an addendum to that followup question, DOM Elements don't even have an exposed "visible" attribute in markup, so the question itself was misguided. The better explanation is that my anchor tag is encapsulated in an asp:Panel which hides the offending anchor tag. I'm assuming your answer still applies?

Comment: @TonyFiorentini in that case maybe not; it depends on what is actually emitted to the user (e.g. on the webpage)

Comment: I see. That was my ultimate question. Because the panels are actually causing the markup not to render, is it safe to use the ID tag more than once, knowing beforehand that only one id will ever exist. And even if it is, are there other reasons why this is a bad coding practice?

Comment: @TonyFiorentini well you do run the risk of unknowingly causing multiple elements with the same ID to render

Comment: I'd say probably the last ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯